# VBA Excel automatically fill cells until set of 4 reached

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image]
I have an Excel 2010 sheet that is filled automatically with data from another worksheet. By hand I have to fill up all the cells in column C with the word “water” until I reach a set of four cells.

I would love to have that done automatically too, but don’t really know where to start.
The problem is that the number of filled cells in column C varies every time (but always with a set of 2 cells). The range of cells that is automatically filled with data is from C8-C55. It is always filled with 2 cells at the same time. When the number of cells cannot be devided by 4, I would like to have more cells in this range filled with the word "water" until the filled number of cells can be devided by 4.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, I don't see "water". Can you post an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

i do not understand what do you mean with "until I reach a set of four cells"
in opposite to "Maximum range is C8-C55".

a simple macro is always possible for this, but i think there is also room for a formula, including the named-range-offset method, but formulas are not my favorite.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to your question. With maximum range I mean that the range of cells that is automatically filled with data is from C8-C55. It is always filled with 2 cells at the same time. When the number of cells cannot be devided by 4, I would like to have more cells in this range filled with the word "water" until the filled number of cells can be devided by 4. Hope this makes more sense. I am not familiar yet with the named-range-offset method. Will look into it today if it can help me with this.